# have Autofac throw if the destination type does not implement certain interface

Tags: c#, autofac

Using Autofac, I have a certain data type (an implementer of `IMapWorld`) registered. I have a certain data type `IMapComposition` that, from an architectural standpoint, is allowed to get an instance of `IMapWorld`. If anyone else attempts to get an instance if `IMapWorld` from the Autofac container, I want an exception thrown. In other words I want something like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MapWorld>().As<IMapWorld>().ForInheritorsOf<IMapComposition>().ElseThrow();
```

Can this be done with Autofac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no first-class feature of Autofac to do that, but you could use the Keyed feature to do it in a way...

```
builder.RegisterType<MapWorld>().Keyed<IMapWorld>(typeof(IMapComposition));
```

and then change the registrations of `IMapComposition` implementors to use

```
.ResolveKeyed<IMapWorld>(typeof(IMapComposition))
```

to resolve their dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to enforce design here so that when someone breaks it, he'll get an exception.

```
        containerBuilder.Register((c, p) =>
        {
            if (!p.Named<bool>("CanResolveIMapWorld")) throw new Exception();
            return new MapWorld();
        });

        containerBuilder.Register( c =>
            new MapComposition
            {
                MapWorld = c.Resolve<IMapWorld>(new NamedParameter("CanResolveIMapWorld", true))
            });
```

Whenever someone tries to resolve IMapWorld normally, without specifying the arbitrary parameter, it'll throw.

Not the cleanest solution, but should prevent accidental design breach. This can be prettyfied a bit by adding custom registration extension methods.